# Negation operator logic not making sense

Tags: objective-c

I'm having trouble understanding with the code below.  It involves a setter with an if statement that requires the origin variable to be zero (false) before executing.

The negation operator in the if statement requires *origin*  to be zero (false) to execute, how come it executes after *origin* is assigned a value.

```
/**implementation file **/
-(void) setOrigin : (XYPoint *) pt
{
    if (! origin)
        origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];

    origin.x = pt.x;
    origin.y = pt.y;
}


/** Main file **/
myPoint.x = 2;
myPoint.y = 3;

shape1.origin= myPoint;

myPoint.x = 2;
myPoint.y = 3;

shape1.origin= myPoint;

}
```

myRect.origin = myPoint;

^^The first time this method appears,the method is executed because the instance variable is zero and (! origin) is valid.

However, if I change the values of myPoint in the next line and set myRect.origin = myPoint again, the setter method shouldn't work because (! origin) is no longer true because it already contains a non zero value from the previous setting execution.  Why does it still execute despite this logic?  Am I wrong?

Comment: You realize that the `if` statement only affects the next line, right?

Comment: Hey @kevin, I think I read somewhere that indenting in objective C makes a big difference if you aren't using brackets in your if/else statements. Because origin.x = pt.x and origin.y = pt.y aren't indented under the if statement, are they not part of the if statement?

Comment: No, indentation makes absolutely no difference in objective c. Those two aren't part of the `if` statement because the `if` only affects the very next statement and nothing else. Period. (Brackets count as a single statement, regardless of how much is inside them).

Comment: @Kevin: You can post an answer now if you like.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about the scope of the `if` statement. The `if` only affects the very next statement, regardless of whitespace. For example:

```
if(NO)
    foo();
bar();
```

`foo` is not called, but `bar` is; I have indented the code properly to emphasize this, but it is important to realize that indentation and even newlines have no effect on the code. I could write the above as:

```
if(NO)foo();bar();
```

and it will be precisely the same. It is for this reason that you have to watch out for empty statements; the following is a common error:

```
if(NO);
    foo();
bar();
```

Did you spot the problem? The semicolon at the end of `if(NO);` counts as ending the (empty) statement the `if` affects! That means that `foo()` will be executed despite its misleading indentation.  Another issue I have run into is this:

```
if(NO)
//    foo();
bar();
```

Did you spot this one? `bar();` is the first statement after the `if`, so it is not called!

Braces, regardless of their content, are a single (compound) statement, so:

```
if(NO) {}
if(NO) {
    foo();
}
if(NO) {
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

I don't think there are any surprises here: everything within the braces is not executed because the braces and all its contents are a single statement.  Using braces prevents the two errors I mention and makes it clear what the programmer intended. For this reason, I suggest always using braces to make explicit what you want the `if` to do.

In your particular case:

```
if (! origin)
    origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];

origin.x = pt.x;
origin.y = pt.y;
```

you could rewrite the `if` with braces to make it clear:

```
if (! origin) {
    origin = [[XYPoint alloc] init];
}

origin.x = pt.x;
origin.y = pt.y;
```

This means "if `origin` is not already an object, initialize it to a new `XYPoint`. If not, don't bother, we don't need or want to create a new object every time.  But regardless of whether you had to create the object or not, set its `x` and `y` coordinates to the ones passed in.

Answer (score 0):

That if statement only checks to see if origin exists, and if origin does not exist, it allocates and initializes origin, before setting the values to the values from the method argument.

Basically it's a convenience method. 
The first time you call it, the origin is created if needed, then set to the arg.

If origin exists then it just proceeds to do the setting.